How do i select all in the video sequencer in python scripting
I want to select whatever I have in my video sequencer and delete it and am writing a python script for it. For stuff like this I make use of the info panel scripting tab, but it doesn't show what I need to use for selecting all video sequences it does however say how to delete (ie, bpy.ops.sequencer.delete())
What is the python code to select all in video sequencer?


I have the answer for your question, but firstly I'd like to share the method I got this info:
To understand how to do something using Python often is useful to find the way to do it manually. The manual way of deleting all strips consists of two actions:

Select > All

Strip > Delete


Now, when we know all needed actions, we just need to get know the Python operators assigned to the buttons we pressed.
To do that we need to enable Python Tooltips option:
Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display > Python Tooltips (set it enabled)

After that every time we hover the mouse pointer over a menu item or a button - the Python tooltip emerges :

Using this method I've got the operator you needed:
import bpy
bpy.ops.sequencer.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.sequencer.delete()


NOTE: while hovering over a button(or menu item) pess Ctrl+C
*this will copy the Python operator.

Now you are also aware of this little trick with tooltips 

Ooh thanks allot. Wasn't aware of python tooltips, very useful!
